# How to keep part of a spreadsheet always visible during navigation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to apologize in advance for asking something that's clearly available on the web. Unfortunately, I don't know the appropriate terminology though.

I'm looking to keep certain rows/columns always shown in excel. For example, in a worksheet with a lot of columns, I always want to see the name that exists on the far left. More importantly, how do I turn this off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Freeze Pane function, as illustrated [here](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/excels_freeze_pane_command_retains_focus).

> Excel has a nice feature called Freeze Panes that can solve such a problem. This feature allows you to keep information from scrolling off the screen when moving through a spreadsheet. As a matter of habit, I always freeze the second row.
>
> …
>
> To freeze columns and rows in Excel,
>
> 1. From the **View** menu, verify you're using **Normal**.
> 2. Click the **row number** just below the area you'd like to freeze. The whole row should highlight.
> 3. **Click the cell** on that highlighted row to the right of the columns you would like to freeze.
> 4. From the **Window** menu, select **Freeze Panes**.

You can also *Unfreeze Panes* using the dropdown box on the *Freeze Panes* button.

Comment: One confusing thing is that Freeze Panes behaves weirdly if you select the very top row: it splits the screen into four equal quarters. Selecting the second row is usually what you want.  So that's something to watch out for, at least in Excel 2003.

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Help**

[Freeze or Lock Rows and Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdf5.png)

I found it Very Difficult to figure out how to do this for the Top row ***and*** for a couple of Columns.
I did figure it out however,

First Split the panes

[image: Excel 2010]

and then move the large black Lines to the rows and columns that you want Static (or Fixed)

you can click `Freeze panes > Freeze Panes` and then click `Split`  or you can just click `Split`. if you do anything else in the `Freeze Panes` and then Try to Split it will only Give you One Thick Black Line.

if your focus is in the are that is Static (Fixed/Locked) and try to scroll you will scroll only that pane.

*I am using Excel 2010*

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel for Mac

Ribbon > View > Freeze section:

[image: Freeze]

> Freeze Panes
> Unfreeze Panes
> Freeze Top Row
> Freeze First Column